# How to Cover entire Screen with <View> in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My Goal is to display an `ActivityIndicator` over the entire screen when the app first loads up to check whether or not the user is already logged in. If so, I navigate to the `App`. Otherwise I stay in the `Login`. My current Code:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   ...
   this.state = {
      loading: true
   }

componentDidMount(){
//look in the database and check whether or not he is logged in and set 'loading' accordingly
}

render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, position: "relative}} >
            {/*creates a View over everything else*/
            this.state.loading &&
            <View style={{
              position: "absolute",
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}>
              <ActivityIndicator size={"large"}/>
          </View>
        }
        ...other views and stuff...
        </View>
    );
}
```

This is working but it does not cover the `header`:
[image: screenshot of login]

Is it possible without using `headerShown: false`?

Help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It should be a new screen with `headerShown` option set to false. You can add this to your main navigator and render conditionally. Why you don't want to use the `headerShown` property?

Comment: I did not use it because I want to have a header. If use `headerShown: false` then I don't have a header

Comment: Sure, but you can have a header hided only for one screen.

Comment: but it then does just plop in right? Or can I make with a transition?

Comment: Yes, just plop in. I think it's normal for mobile apps, but if you want some animation after navigating to this screen, maybe you can put some callback to it. 

Screen1 -> click on button with some async function -> navigate to loadingScreen and provide to it some callback function -> call navigate function from callback and back to the Screen1.

I don't know if this is the best solution for that, but maybe it will help :)

Comment: No the thing is all this should happen on one screen: The app starts and goes to the loginScreen immediately. There is an ActivityIndicator. In this screen I want to have a header but the ActivityIndicator (the View around it) doesn't cover the header, that is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: You activity indicator/splash should be outside the navigator, not inside the login screen

Comment: Yup, in my opinion you should create a separated screen for loading.